# A possible multi account

Tags: discussion, multiple-accounts

I have noticed that there are suspicious similarities between these two users:

- [John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286337/john-smith)
- [miik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930299/miik)

The two have both asked several questions in the last couple of hours, all of them related to lists in Python. Secondly, all of these questions seems to follow the same format:

I have these lists. How can I do this?

Without providing any code they had tried.

After [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164510/removing-something-from-a-list-using-a-list-of-tuples#comment23100830_16164510) (which 6 people seem to agree with me on) I made on one of the questions, the stream of questions from both users seemed to stop abruptly. They both also seem to use the [wxpython](/questions/tagged/wxpython) and [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) quite a bit at well.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14673195/1907098) question, in which one accepted another's answer, although that could just be a coincidence, as I haven't found another question like that so far.

However, one seems to have been on SO for much longer than the other (10 months), so I could be wrong here.

Comment: Flag one of their contributions for moderator attention using the "other" option and explain what you've noticed.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, you're technically allowed to have multiple accounts as long as they don't interact, and as long as it's not to evade a suspension or a ban.

Comment: @Mysticial Both users ran into the 6 questions per day limit, I strongly suspect that this is the reason for the second account. And evading such a limit by using sock puppets is certainly not allowed.

Comment: User John-Smith has upvoted on 18 answer and miik has only 1 answer , so I assume that these user have other accounts also.

Comment: He maybe suffer from schizophrenia, and that's not funny. Let him go.

Comment: @MadScientist Ah... I wasn't aware of that. Yes that'd be circumventing a limit.

Comment: @Lucifer Or they genuinely upvoted the answers of other users.

Comment: @Lucifer 18 upvotes isn't a lot for an account that has asked 60+ questions. They could be legitimate upvotes on the answers that the OP received.

Comment: @Bart yes, that is also possible, that's why i use word **I assume**

Comment: Pretty common, either one person creating another account or two friends fooling around.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, like this [“Up-vote me and I'll up-vote you” sort of deals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140788/173001)